# iTunes: installation error

Tags: windows-7, itunes, software-rec

for some reason I can't install iTunes on my system (Windows 7, 32bit), progress bar goes nearly to the end and then i've got this error. Anybody had similar problem? I wonder if there is any good alternative for iTunes (freeware or gpl)?

Thank you.

[image]
<sub>(source: [pokazywarka.pl](http://img.pokazywarka.pl/images/111187/266934.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJSLBNACOS3UTO6HA&Signature=m8Ro3n4gAWtOCg9d69znfZjPGzg%3D&Expires=1265029200))</sub>

Comment: Be glad you can't install it! Awful software!

Comment: If you're not married to an iPod, Zune is actually a pretty good alternative, especially with the Zune pass if you're looking to go the legit route :)

Comment: yes, I agree with @Chris, Zune Software is a very high quality solution (a little heavy on resources, but runs faster than iTunes)...use it all the time myself...

Comment: Why the iTunes bashing? Zune Software is great but it doesn't have smart playlists and the Genius system works out better in iTunes. Those are two of the reasons I switched to iTunes after using Zune Software for a pretty long time. The day I will leave iTunes? That's the day I discover something that iTunes is missing which I would need. ( http://superuser.com/questions/157462/how-manage-music-collection-ebooks-on-windows/157467#157467 )

Comment: c1: What error did you have?

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7programs/thread/f4dd5033-9bcb-4788-b100-5e98bd80f6bf) may help.

> I've managed to solve this: Install
>   the following "Microsoft Visual C++
>   2005 Service Pack 1 Redistributable
>   Package ATL Security Update" from
>   http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=766a6af7-ec73-40ff-b072-9112bab119c2&displaylang=en#filelist
>
> It looks like there was a problem in
>   the way upgrades for this
>   distributions were managed

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using it for syncing with an iPod, the market is flooded with free "alternatives". I say "alternatives" because using iTunes on windows is like shooting oneself in the foot with a rusty harpoon. Twice.

Try [WinAMP](http://www.winamp.com), or my personal favourite [Foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org) (Which has an iPod plugin [here](http://yuo.be/ipod.php), which may or may not still work, and may or may not continue working into the future. It's apple, and they don't like not being in control, so YMMV).

I'd stress that if you're not using iTunes for iPod things, don't use it. It's nice software on OS X, but the windows port isn't.